# How to pass data in tableview from nscounter set

Tags: ios, arrays, set, tableview

How to pass data in `tableview`

```
//count duplication data in
NSMutableArray *totaluniqarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:column2Array];
orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:totaluniqarray];
uniqtotal = [[orderedSet set] allObjects]; 
countedSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:totaluniqarray]; 
for(int i=0;i<[uniqtotal count];i++)
{ 
   NSLog(@"%@ %lu",[uniqtotal objectAtIndex:i], (unsigned long)[countedSet countForObject: [uniqtotal objectAtIndex:i]]);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

2016-01-07 03:00:28.881 ammpp[4033:45473] 915556666667  2
2016-01-07 03:00:28.881 ammpp[4033:45473] 917565222221  10
2016-01-07 03:00:28.881 ammpp[4033:45473] 919885255556  2
2016-01-07 03:00:28.882 ammpp[4033:45473] 911168555500  3
2016-01-07 03:00:28.882 ammpp[4033:45473] 918777711119  9
2016-01-07 03:00:28.882 ammpp[4033:45473] 486666690091  18
```

This code is to count a duplicate items in array. This is output. I want only `countForObject` to be displayed in in `tableView`.

Comment: It is unclear what you actually want here. Please add some more detail. How and what data you want to populate data in table view.

Comment: i want 2,10,2,3,9,18

Answer (score 0):

First in `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` return

```
return [uniqtotal count]
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do something like:

```
cell.textLabel.text =[@((unsigned long)[countedSet countForObject: [uniqtotal objectAtIndex:i]]) stringValue]
```

Comment: only i want to duplication total like 2,10,2,3 not a number.

Comment: and I believe this line `(unsigned long)[countedSet countForObject: [uniqtotal objectAtIndex:i]]` print `2,10,2,3` right?

Comment: if return [uniqtotal count] pass to show all number..i want only duplication data..

Comment: cell.titleLabel.text =[@((unsigned long)[countedSet countForObject: [uniqtotal objectAtIndex:i]]) stringValue] i written a this code .only first record show in tableview..like first record 2 ,10,2,7 only 2 show in tableview